# Why is there a problem in Firefox connecting to a particular site securely?

Tags: firefox

I installed ubuntu 11.10 very recently, not incredibly IT literate, finding my way around.

Can't connect from Firefox to my.virginmedia.com.

I'm warned against continuing because someone may be trying to impersonate the site

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I would say that's a problem. First make sure you've installed any updates by opening the Update Manager and doing a refresh. Install any updates, restart Firefox and try again. It also might be worth trying another browser, like Google Chrome (just to see if it has the same issues).

If it's still showing as a security issue, that could well mean that there is somebody or something between you and the website trying to eavesdrop or interfere with the communication between your browser and the server.

I'm speculating and it could just be an out-of-date certificate that needs to be updated. If updating doesn't help, you should edit your question to include the details about the certificate. Firefox should be able to tell you why it's not happy.

But I would approach this suspiciously. It never hurts to be too suspicious when your online credentials are at risk.